# Creating nicknames for command arguments

Tags: bash, email, variable

I would like to use a nickname (foo) for my email address (foo@domain.com). The goal is to be able to do

```
echo "This is a test email" | mail -s "Email Title" foo
```

instead of

```
echo "This is a test email" | mail -s "Email Title" foo@domain.com
```

Thank you.

As a side-note, when running the former line I am able to send the mail as expected, it is just sent to foo@something. That is, it is not recognizing the alias as put in `/etc/aliases`. I have also edited the msmtp configuration file as to permit aliases from `/etc/aliases`.

**Update**

By appending the line `aliases   /etc/aliases` to `/etc/msmtprc` and appending `foo: foo@domain.com` to `/etc/aliases`, I am able to run the following command successfully:
`echo "Hello" | msmtp tutmail`

However, this does not work with the `mail` command which I prefer.

Comment: What MTA are you using? this sounds like something that ought to be handled by a *mail alias* rather than at the shell level

Comment: Could very well be! I am using msmtp.

Comment: Please provide an example of the line in `/etc/aliases`. What's the "_something_" in the context of "_foo@something_"? If it's your local box, please say so.

Answer (score 1):

Use a shell variable?

```bsh
foo='foo@domain.com'

echo "This is a test email" | mail -s "Email Title" "$foo"
```

The variable `foo`'s value is got by prefixing the variable's name with `$`.

The quoting of `"$foo"` is generally needed to avoid splitting the variable's value on whitespace (for e.g. values like `"My Name" <hello@example.com>`) and will also avoid using the variable's value as a filename globbing pattern.

Comment: I was hoping there was a "nicer" solution than using a shell variable. That is in the sense that I would like to avoid the usage of "$" and """ extra characters. But maybe I am just stubborn..  thanks anyway:)

Comment: The other choice with bash is to use a function: `foo() { echo "foo@domain.com"; }` then `mail -s title $(foo) < body`, but that's not any less syntax. With zsh you'd use a "global alias"

Answer (score 1):

If this question is just about mail see the section "[Personal and systemwide distribution lists](https://linux.die.net/man/1/mail)"

> It is also possible to create a personal distribution lists so that, for instance, the user can send mail to 'cohorts' and have it go to a group of people. Such lists can be defined by placing a line like

> ```
>    alias cohorts bill ozalp jkf mark kridle@ucbcory
> ```

> in the file .mailrc in the user's home directory. The current list of such aliases can be displayed with the alias command in mailx. System wide distribution lists can be created by editing /etc/aliases, see aliases(5) and sendmail(8); these are kept in a different syntax. In mail the user sends, personal aliases will be expanded in mail sent to others so that they will be able to reply to the recipients. System wide aliases are not expanded when the mail is sent, but any reply returned to the machine will have the system wide alias expanded as all mail goes through sendmail.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I created ".mailrc" in my user home directory and added the line `alias foo foo@domain.com`. This did not work.

Comment: Try adding `foo: foo@domain.com` to `/etc/aliases`. Depending on your setup you may need to run `newaliases` or restart your mail service.

Comment: ...it looks like you may also need to modify the configuration file to enable reading of the `/etc/aliases` file: see for example [msmtp: Using the mail command](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Msmtp#Using_the_mail_command)

Comment: I have added `foo: foo@domain.com` to `/etc/aliases`, and I have changed the msmtp configuration file to accept aliases from `/etc/aliases`. Yet it does still not work. Writing out the address in full works `echo "This is a test email" | mail -s "Email Title" foo@domain.com` yet not with `echo "This is a test email" | mail -s "Email Title" foo`.

Comment: @tutentaten  Did you run the `newaliases` command to rebuild the `aliases` database?

Comment: Yes. I did do that.